# Automatically support Greek, Hindi and other languages as Unicode chars?

Tags: unicode, greek, alphabet

I learned from [Davislor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558064/85416) answer that I tell LaTeX to warn me if a missing glyph is detected. I can then declare it with this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{FiraSans}
\setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf}
\setmonofont{Fira Code}

\newfontfamily\firamono{Fira Mono}[Ligatures={Common,Discretionary,TeX}]

\newunicodechar{⇒}{{\sffamily ⇒}}
\newunicodechar{⊕}{{\sffamily ⊕}}
\newunicodechar{│}{{\sffamily │}}
\newunicodechar{┬}{{\sffamily ┬}}
\newunicodechar{♯}{{\sffamily ♯}}
\newunicodechar{⨼}{{\sffamily ⨼}}
\newunicodechar{◿}{{\sffamily ◿}}
% ...
\newunicodechar{α}{$\alpha$}
\newunicodechar{δ}{$\delta$}
\newunicodechar{ε}{$\varepsilon$}
\newunicodechar{η}{$\eta$}
\newunicodechar{ι}{$\iota$}
\newunicodechar{κ}{$\kappa$}
\newunicodechar{λ}{$\lambda$}
\newunicodechar{μ}{$\mu$}
\newunicodechar{π}{$\pi$}
\newunicodechar{ω}{$\omega$}
% ...
```

However, now that I use `\tracinglostchars=2` in my [document](https://github.com/heig-tin-info/handout) I noticed I have plenty of missing glyphs. Most of them are regular greek letters and I would like to know if I need to declare one `newunicodechar` for each of them or if there smarter alternatives. Here the missing glyphs:

```
$ perl -ne 'print if s/Missing.+?no\K(.+?) in font (.*?):/$1\t$2/' _build/latex/main.log | sort -u
       Fira Code Regular/OT
       [lmroman10-regular]
 ː      [lmroman10-regular]
 α      [lmroman10-regular]
 δ      [lmroman10-regular]
 ε      [lmroman10-regular]
 η      [lmroman10-regular]
 ι      [lmroman10-regular]
 κ      [lmroman10-regular]
 λ      [lmroman10-regular]
 μ      [lmroman10-regular]
 ο      [lmroman10-regular]
 π      [lmroman10-regular]
 ρ      [lmroman10-regular]
 ς      [lmroman10-regular]
 τ      [lmroman10-regular]
 ω      [lmroman10-regular]
 ό      [lmroman10-regular]
 ا      [lmroman10-regular]
 ب      [lmroman10-regular]
 ت      [lmroman10-regular]
 ر      [lmroman10-regular]
 س      [lmroman10-regular]
 ع      [lmroman10-regular]
 ن      [lmroman10-regular]
 َ       [lmroman10-regular]
 ِ       [lmroman10-regular]
 پ      [lmroman10-regular]
 ک      [lmroman10-regular]
 ह      Fira Code Regular/OT
 இ      [lmroman10-regular]
 ச      [lmroman10-regular]
 ஜ      [lmroman10-regular]
 ன      [lmroman10-regular]
 ம      [lmroman10-regular]
 ர      [lmroman10-regular]
 வ      [lmroman10-regular]
 ா      [lmroman10-regular]
 ி      [lmroman10-regular]
 ீ       [lmroman10-regular]
 ு      [lmroman10-regular]
 ்       [lmroman10-regular]
 Ἐ      [lmroman10-regular]
 ῆ      [lmroman10-regular]
 ‎       [lmroman10-regular]
 ⇒      Fira Code Regular/OT
 ∧      [lmroman10-bold]
 ≈      [lmroman10-regular]
 ≡      [lmroman10-regular]
 ⊕      Fira Code Regular/OT
 ⊕      [lmroman10-regular]
 │      [lmroman8-italic]
 ┬      [lmroman8-italic]
 ♯      Fira Code Regular/OT
 ➀      [lmroman10-regular]
 ➁      [lmroman10-regular]
 ➂      [lmroman10-regular]
 ⨼      Fira Code Regular/OT
 〰     [ipaexm.ttf]/OT
 话     [ipaexm.ttf]/OT
 국     [ipaexm.ttf]/OT
 어     [ipaexm.ttf]/OT
 한     [ipaexm.ttf]/OT
 ◿      Fira Code Regular/OT
```

I tried to include `\usepackage{kotex}` to have the Korean Hangul but then I have this clash:

```
Package fontspec Warning: Font "FandolHei-Regular" does not contain requested
(fontspec)                Script "CJK".
```

Comment: `\newunicodechar{α}{$\alpha$}` is nonsense. α (U+03B1) is a text character, not a mathematical symbol, the mathematical alpha is U+1D6FC, .

Comment: Defining `\newunicodechar{α}{$\alpha$}` is not a good idea. Among other things, in math mode, it will switch you to text mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly want to use `babel` or `polyglossia` for a multilingual document such as this.  [Here is an example.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483605/creating-a-document-with-mixed-languages)